# How to make multiple virtualhost in docker with php5.6-apache container?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, docker, virtual-host

I am trying to create virtual host in container `php5.6-apache` but when I try to run the command a2ensite.

my host_1 file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName local.website1.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/codeigniter_first/public_html/
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/html/codeigniter_first/public_html/">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

my host_2 file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName local.website2.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/codeigniter_second/public_html/
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

  <Directory "/var/www/html/codeigniter_second/public_html/">
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My Docker file:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.2-apache
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
COPY php56.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

COPY sites/website1.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website1.com.conf
COPY sites/website2.com.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website2.com.conf
```

My Docker composer file:

```
version: "2"
services:
########################################################
#### PHP and Apache Config
########################################################
    www:
        build:
            context: ./docker-config/php-apache
            args:
                - PHP_VERSION=5.6-apache
                - XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST=192.168.1.70
        container_name: rp-app-workspace
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - "./workdir-apps:/var/www/html/"
            - "./docker-config/php-apache/logs:/var/log/apache2"
            - "./docker-config/php-apache/sites:/etc/apache2/sites-available"
        links:
            - db
            - memcached
        networks:
            - default
########################################################
#### Volume Configuration
########################################################
volumes:
    persistent:
```

When I build my docker container virtual hosts does not works.
when I try to add commands to run `a2ensite` in docker file it shows me error `ERROR: Site website1.com does not exist!` for building

```
RUN a2ensite website1.com.conf
RUN a2ensite website2.com.conf
```

I also try to change the position of copy the file at top and run command at bottom of the docker file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong directory for placing virtual host configuration files. It should be `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, so you need to change COPY destination paths
from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf`

When your run `a2ensite website1.com.conf` command, it will create configuration symlink in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` directory.